# Age Calculator gone wrong

Tags: php

code 1:
the code 1 works fine but when i tried to add this code to my html by getting value from user and output the answer i am unable to do please help i m totally confused

```
#Code 1
<?php
$dateOfBirth = "25-05-1994";
$today       = date("Y-m-d");
$diff        = date_diff(date_create($dateOfBirth), date_create($today));
echo 'Age is' . $diff->format('%yYears, %mMonths, %dDays');
?>

#code 2
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Excel To HTML using codebeautify.org
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Age calculator
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateOfBirth'];
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$diff = date_diff(date_create($dateOfBirth, $today));
}
echo 'Age is' .  $diff->format('%yYears, %mMonths, %dDays');
?>
        <form method="post" action="">
          <input type="text" name="dateOfBirth"/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem please. Do you get an error?

Comment: Did you check your `$_POST['dateOfBirth']`?

Comment: First Silly Question: Is this file saved with a `.php` extension?

Comment: You are missing `date_create($today)` in your code 2

Comment: date_create($today) was missing thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code 2 change

`$diff = date_diff(date_create($dateOfBirth, $today));`

to `$diff = date_diff(date_create($dateOfBirth), date_create($today));` just like you do on code 1